# Update method doesn't get the form input from edit method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create and update a contract. `create` works fine. But my update takes the default value instead of the value from my edit. Why? My end of date is always the next year of start date.

```
 before_filter :only => :create do
   @contract = Contract.new(params[:contract])
     if @contract.start_date.present?
       n = @contract.num_years
       n = n.blank? ? 1 : n.to_i
       @contract.end_date = @contract.start_date + n.years - 1.day
     end
   @contract.save!
   Mailers.delay(queue: "Mailers").contract_created_notification(@contract)
 end
 controller do
   def update
    @contract = Contract.find(params[:id])
     if @contract.start_date.present?
       n = @contract.num_years
       n = n.blank? ? 1 : n.to_i
       @contract.end_date = @contract.start_date + n.years - 1.day
       update!
       Mailers.delay(queue: "Mailers").contract_created_notification(@contract)
     end
   end
```

log file:

> INSERT INTO `delayed_jobs` (`attempts`, `created_at`, `failed_at`, `handler`, `last_error`, `locked_at`, `locked_by`, `priority`, `queue`, `run_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (0, '2014-07-30 06:41:57', NULL, '--- !ruby/object:Delayed::PerformableMailer\nobject: !ruby/class \'Mailers\'\nmethod_name: :contract_created_notification\nargs:\n- !ruby/ActiveRecord:Contract\n attributes:\n id: 464\n school_id: 370\n start_date: 2014-07-01\n end_date: 2022-06-30\n num_students: 900\n pymt_status: false\n created_at: &1 2014-07-30 06:41:57.876186386 Z\n updated_at: *1\n', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 'Mailers', '2014-07-30 06:41:57', '2014-07-30 06:41:57')

```
> Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"F7W4ccjQe8wk8Z9VZB18efJBhHp6LPCtifC6PDYVEF0=", "contract"=>{"start_date(1i)"=>"2014", "start_date(2i)"=>"7", "start_date(3i)"=>"1", "num_years"=>"5", "num_students"=>"100", "pymt_status"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Update Contract", "id"=>"465"}

 INSERT INTO `delayed_jobs` (`attempts`, `created_at`, `failed_at`, `handler`, `last_error`, `locked_at`, `locked_by`, `priority`, `queue`, `run_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (0, '2014-07-30 08:23:24', NULL, '--- !ruby/object:Delayed::PerformableMailer\nobject: !ruby/class \'Mailers\'\nmethod_name: :contract_notification\nargs:\n- !ruby/ActiveRecord:Contract\n attributes:\n id: 465\n school_id: 370\n start_date: 2014-07-01\n end_date: 2015-06-30\n num_students: 100\n pymt_status: false\n created_at: 2014-07-30 08:04:22.000000000 Z\n updated_at: 2014-07-30 08:23:24.782557418 Z\n', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 'Mailers', '2014-07-30 08:23:24', '2014-07-30 08:23:24')
```

Comment: {a} I see the log from the create action, but could you add the log from the update action as well, which is manifesting the problem? {b} Your log should also include the parameters being posted, eg `Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "topic"=>"General", ... }` -- this line, from both the create and the update repros, would also be quite helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Strange Controller Code**

My attention was initially drawn here:

```
before_filter :only => :create do
```

and

```
controller do
```

What are these exactly? They don't look like typical Rails controller code:

--

```
#app/controllers/contracts_controller.rb
Class ContractsController < ApplicationController
   before_action :set_vars, only: [:edit, :update]

   def new
      @contract = Contract.new
   end

   def create
      @contract = Contract.new(contract_params)
      @contract.set_date if @contract.start_date.present?
      @contract.save
   end

   def update
      @contract.set_date if @contract.start_date.present?
      @contract.update(contract_params)
   end

   private

   def set_vars
       @contract = Contract.find params[:id]
   end

   def set_date
       n = self.num_years
       n = n.blank? ? 1 : n.to_i
       self.end_date = self.start_date + n.years - 1.day
   end

   def contract_params
      params.require(:contract).permit(:contract, :attributes)
   end
end
```

---

**Date**

Although I'm not exactly sure how to remedy your issue, I think getting the controller sorted will be the first step.

If you wanted to set the `end_date` as per the `num_years` attribute, I'd suggest that you'll have to consider the `edit` method's passing of the `num_years` attribute, which you can then pass through to the `update` action

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I am using active admin. How can i change my coding according to that?